# How do you figure out the MEDIAN of a column taking into account filters?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I've recently discovered that you can use `SUBTOTAL` for various functions which allow you to sum up or find totals of a column, even whilst there are filters being applied to it.

However, the list of functions `SUBTOTAL` has does not include `MEDIAN`.

Is it possible to find the median of a column of numbers taking into that some rows have filtered out?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Updated to pick up comments from lori_m below

**1. Original answer - all xl versions**
Courtesy of [Aladin Akyurek from this solution](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/subtotal-using-median-functoin-t1753713.html)
If your data was in A1:A10, array enter this formula with [shift](/questions/tagged/shift)[ctrl](/questions/tagged/ctrl)[enter](/questions/tagged/enter)
`=MEDIAN(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(A1:A10,ROW(A1:A10)-MIN(ROW(A1:A10)),,1)),A1:A10))`

**2. Updated answer (non-array) - all xl versions**
`=MEDIAN(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(A1:A10,MMULT(ROW(A1:A10),1)-MIN(MMULT(ROW(A1:A10),1)),,1)),A1:A10))`

**3. Excel 2010 & Excel 2013**
`=AGGREGATE(12,5,A1:A10)`

Comment: @brettdj : thanks it worked. do you know what the reason you have to press shift ctrl and enter?

Comment: @Diskdrive: In Excel 2010 or 2013 preview you can just use: `=AGGREGATE(12,5,A1:A10)`. The formula above is an array formula - see for instance: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArrayFormulas.aspx but you can enter it normally by changing `ROW(A1:A10)` to `MMULT(ROW(A1:A10),1)`.

Comment: @lori_m I like the `MMULT` approach (in terms of cross xl version approach).

Comment: @brettdj: me too... in my Excel 2010, the non-array version fills over twice as fast and recalcs 10% quicker (tested by copying down 100,000 cells).

Answer (score 0):

True, `SUBTOTAL` does not include `MEDIAN` but you can obtain it by first using the `SUBTOTAL` and then **substituting a part of the Excel formula** in several or more columns/cells where you need the `MEDIAN`.

Imagine you used `AVERAGE` in the Excel subtotal function, then the formula would be for instance =SUBTOTAL(1;E10:E12)
Now, replace all occurrences of **`"SUBTOTAL(1;"`** with **`"MEDIAN("`** (without the quotes).