# worksheetfunction.median issue with range

Tags: vba, excel

i have a userform which takes a textbox input into a filter query:

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim kbnumber As String
Dim lastrow As Long



Set ws1 = Sheets("Incident")
Set ws2 = Sheets("KB Articles")

lastrow = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


ws1.Range("M1:A" & lastrow).AutoFilter field:=13, Criteria1:=txtKB

ws1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
```

i am able to filter out the query but i'm unable to get the median.

basically i was trying to get the median using:

```
worksheetfunction.median(columns(2))
```

but it includes all the values of the column including the hidden ones.

i need help with how to properply implement the .median function.

thanks.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161108/how-do-you-figure-out-the-median-of-a-column-taking-into-account-filters Use the `Application.Evaluate` function if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Excel 2010, the native worksheet [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) should be available as either,

```
kbnumber = Application.Aggregate(12, 5, ws1.Columns(2))
' or,
kbnumber = WorksheetFunction.Aggregate(12, 5, ws1.Columns(2))
```

See the documentation for a full list of functions and available options for [AGGREGATE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF).

Comment: I think you should use `ws1.Columns(2)` instead of just `Columns(2)` else it will come out with compilation error.

Comment: @keongkenshih - Good catch. I'm afraid I was imposing my own coding style into the isolated line of code. Thanks.

Comment: actually the code you wrote just now was correct just you need using `With ws1` and `End With` , else you will end up having compilation error.

Comment: hi thanks. for this. googled everyhwere and never got the aggregate function. this looks correct. and i've tested it with a standard deviation calculator and it works!! thanks!

Comment: yeah i also noticed the .columns and yes it did return an error :) but that's fine. thanks a lot!